# Create repository method, that will log information to database(mysql) table.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am developing Laravel 5 app. In which I want to log information to database table whenever user creates or updates item.

I have created new migration file - Logs. In Logs table I want to store information: which USER changed or added something, which TABLE have been changed and OLD VALUE and NEW VALUE.

In my opinion, the easiest way to do this, is to create new repository method and somehow connect store and update methods with new log method.

This is how my repository looks like:

```
private function log()
{
    // place for log method
}

public function store($request)
{
    Radar::create([
        'date' => $request->input('date'),
        'number' => $request->input('number'),
        'distance' => $request->input('distance'),
        'time' => $request->input('time'),
        'speed' => $request->input('distance') / $request->input('time') * 3.6,
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
}

public function update($request, $radar)
{
    $radar->date = $request->input('date');
    $radar->number = $request->input('number');
    $radar->distance = $request->input('distance');
    $radar->time = $request->input('time');
    $radar->speed = $request->input('distance') / $request->input('time') * 3.6;
    $radar->user_id = auth()->id();
    $radar->save();
    $this->log($radar);
}
```

I want simple reusable solution without writing too much of a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) or [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers) for this or use a package like [revisionable](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/revisionable)

You can listen to the eloquent events

```
Event::listen('eloquent.created: *', function($model) {
    // log stuff
});
```

You can define this in the EventServiceProvider

---

Or if it's one or a few models that you want to log:

```
class Radar extends Model 
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function($radar) {
            // log stuff
        });

        static::updated(function($radar) {
            // log stuff
        });

        // will be triggered on both created and updatd
        // static::saved(function($radar) {
            // log stuff
        // });
    }   
}
```

---

With the revisionable package you can simple include a trait and define which fields you want to track.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sofa\Revisionable\Laravel\Revisionable; // trait

class User extends Model
{
    use Revisionable;

    /*
     * Set revisionable whitelist - only changes to any
     * of these fields will be tracked during updates.
     */
    protected $revisionable = [
        'email',
        'name',
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and informative answer. Cheers!